# Only run code if iOS < 6.0 with preprocessing?

Tags: ios, xcode

I can find many examples on how to only compile/run code then iOS version is > something, but how do I do it the other way around? I tried the following by running iOS 5.0 in the simulator:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < __IPHONE_6_0
// Code for iOS < 6.0 here
#endif
```

But the code inside the `#if - #endif` is not run on iOS 5.0 in the simulator. How can I do this?

[EDIT]
Ok so I wasn't sure what I wanted it seems, sorry :) The thing is that I want this code in my UITableViewDelegate to be run only if the device is running iOS < 6.0:

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
}
```

This is because I want to do some styling if I am running iOS < 6, but on iOS 6 I can do this styling much much easier. But a version check at runtime inside this method is not really what I want because then it is to late.

Thank you
Søren

Comment: why do you think a check at runtime is too late?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a difference between

1. a compile-time check if you're compiling against a specific SDK and
2. checking which OS your code is running on

Checking for the __IPHONE_6_0 macro will just check which target you're compiling for... is that what you want? If so, you could use `#ifndef __IPHONE_6_0` to check if you are **not compiling** for iOS 6.

If you want to know which OS your code is running on, you can check MSK's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15542116/210171).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a run time not compile time check.

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
```

use it like

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0"))
{

}